# Full-list of cited authors appearing in text and duplicate author name in the reference list

Tags: natbib

I had this problem with a different documentclass, I posted here, but it was not solved. I have now the same problem with a different .cls. I would like to have in the text citation in the author-year format (not number) and in the bibliography the full list of authors (even when 1,000 authors). My layout is in the text a textual citation, as wanted, but this is followed by the full list of authors. Moreover, in the reference list the name of the author is duplicated. I use nsf.cls downloaded at (https://github.com/amrabed/NSF-LaTeX-Template/blob/master/style/nsf.cls) and I use jponew.bst and aasjournal.bst. If I implement natbib or bibtex the nsf.cls does not produce the nsf.bbl file. Here code sample:

```
\documentclass{nsf} 
\begin{document} 
\cite{...} 
\end{document}
```

with

```
\bibliographystyle{jponew}
```

I have the same two problems in the layout using plainnat. Any help would be very appreciated.